# How do I resolve this WCF exception?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm having trouble with a WCF service. The return type is a semi-complex type which makes reference to various basic types and a base interface that each of those types inherits from.

In my debugging, the total byte size of the serialized message is well under the default 65535 byte threshold. Nevertheless, I have increased the maxReceivedMessageSize attribute to 1000000 and the problem remains.

**The WCF service is defined as follows:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILoggingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    NotesInfo ListNotes(NotesQueryOptions options);
}
```

**Here is the definition for the NotesInfo return object:**

```
[DataContract]
public class NotesInfo
{
    [DataMember] public List<TokenizedNote> Notes { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public Dictionary<long, User> Users { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public Dictionary<long, NoteCategory> NoteCategories { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<long, IIdentifiable<long>>> EntitiesByToken { get; set; }
}
```

**When I try to call the service, I get the following exception thrown:**

> The server did not provide a
>   meaningful reply; this might be caused
>   by a contract mismatch, a premature
>   session shutdown or an internal server
>   error. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   The server did not provide a
>   meaningful reply; this might be caused
>   by a contract mismatch, a premature
>   session shutdown or an internal server
>   error.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 242:
Line 243: public AxeFrog.Mobile.NotesInfo ListNotes(AxeFrog.Mobile.NotesQueryOptions options) {
Line 244:            return base.Channel.ListNotes(options);
Line 245:        }
Line 246:    }
```

> Source File:
>   C:\Users\Nathan\Work\Internal
>   Projects\AxeFrog
>   System\Source\Trunk\AxeFrog.Mobile.WebInterface\Service
>   References\LoggingServiceReference\Reference.cs
>   Line: 244

**Below is the code for the other entities involved:**

```
public interface IIdentifiable<TID>
{
    TID ID { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Note : IIdentifiable<long>
{
    [DataMember] public long ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public long? UserID { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public long NoteCategoryID { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public NoteType NoteType { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Message { get; set; }
}

public enum NoteType
{
    Information = 0,
    Warning = 10,
    Failure = 20
}

[DataContract]
public class NoteCategory : IIdentifiable<long>
{
    [DataMember] public long ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class NoteEntityType : IIdentifiable<long>
{
    [DataMember] public long ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public Type TypeName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TokenizedNote
{
    [DataMember] public Note Note { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public List<NoteSegment> NoteSegments { get; set; }
}

public abstract class NoteSegment
{
    public abstract string Render(INoteRenderer renderer, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<long, IIdentifiable<long>>> entitiesByToken);
}

[DataContract]
public class NoteTextSegment : NoteSegment
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class NoteEntitySegment : NoteSegment
{
    [DataMember] public long EntityID { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I have removed the Render() overrides from the abstract implementations of NoteSegment for the sake of readability.

**Here is some info from thedebugger so you can see what is being returned:**

[image]
[image]

Any insight into what I might be doing wrong here would be appreciated. A Google search yields little in the way of useful answers.

Comment: is this ona corporate LAN behind a firewall? In that case, I would recommend the NetTcp binding - much faster and more efficient that the standard, rather heavy-weight wsHttpBinding...

Comment: but netTcp needs either IIS7 (Win Server 2008 or higher or Vista) or self-hosting

Comment: No, it's all on localhost at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You show an exception on the client; what happens when you attach a debugger on the server (or turn on logging), see anything useful there?

Comment: There is no error on the server side. It successfully constructs and returns the return object.

Comment: Hm.  Any chance server and client have mismatched contracts (e.g. server contract changed, but client did not)?  Might need to use e.g. Fiddler to see what's going on the wire.

Comment: Do other methods on the contract interface work?  What if you just return an 'int'?  I would guess serialization maybe next, and try various data types to see if you can come up with conditions for it failing/succeeding...

Comment: I have another service side by side which returns simpler types and it works fine.

Comment: Sounds like you have a recipe for a binary search of the problem.  You have a service with simple types that works.  You have a service with complex types that doesn't.  Start transforming the simple one into the complex one, step by step, until it fails, and find different axes of failure, until you understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by a message too long. You should try to change the limits by editing your app.config like this:

```
<binding name="WebBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The third sentence in the opening paragraph of the question reads: "In my debugging, the total byte size of the serialized message is well under the default 65535 byte threshold."

Comment: @Nathan : the message length is not the only meaningfull threshold. Namely, check the maxArrayLength parameter

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your server just takes a tad too long to put together the response? The default "sendTimeout" on the client is only 60 seconds - you could try to increase that to something higher:

```
<binding name="TweakedBinding" sendTimeout="120" />
```

What does your client config look like? What binding are you using? What security settings?

Marc

**UPDATE:**
could you add the service debug behavior to your service, so that you'd get more debug and error info on the client end when something goes wrong??

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehavior>
    <behavior name="YourBehaviorName">
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehavior>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: No, the response is very quick. I've just updated the question to show a screenshot of the debugger info.

Comment: The binding and security configuration are all default values generated by Visual Studio. The service is via ASP.Net and set to run via IIS rather than the built-in web server.

Answer (score 0):

This question is way old, but I'll throw this out there in case someone else finds it useful. My guess at what's going on here is the inheritance from NoteSegment - you'll need to use the KnownType attribute to tell TokenizedNote object that it can expect NoteTextSegment and NoteEntitySegment when it deserializes (since by default it would only expect an instance of NoteSegment).

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(NoteEntitySegment)]
[KnownType(typeof(NoteTextSegment)]
public class TokenizedNote
{
    [DataMember] public Note Note { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public List<NoteSegment> NoteSegments { get; set; }
}
```

See this resource for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. After spending a mind bending 2 hours on this and trying to find an answer online, I decided to follow the approach to seralize and deserialize the return value/object on the server side using the System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer and finally found that I had missed to add EnumMember attribute on one of the Enums.

Here is the code snippet that helped me resolve the issue:

```
      var dataContractSerializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
      byte[] serializedBytes;
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream mem1 = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(mem1, results);
            serializedBytes = mem1.ToArray();
        }

        MyObject deserializedResult;
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream mem2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(serializedBytes))
        {
            deserializedResult = (MyObject)dataContractSerializer.ReadObject(mem2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS, select the site, click "Basic Settings", then click "Test Settings". What I had overlooked is that the site needs valid credentials as well as its app pool.